# Its possible to show JDatePickerImpl on right side of button instated of down in java?

Tags: java, datepicker

I am using JDatePickerImpl and want to show right or left side of button
instated of bottom please help me out
Code :

```
UtilDateModel model = null;
Properties property = null;
JDatePanelImpl datePanel = null;

try{

    model = new UtilDateModel();
    model.setSelected(true);
    property = new Properties();
    property.put("text.today", "Today");
    property.put("text.month", "Month");
    property.put("text.year", "Year");
    datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model,property);

    f_ObjDateLabelFormatter = new DateLabelFormatter();
    m_fromDateChooser = new 
    JDatePickerImpl(datePanel,f_ObjDateLabelFormatter);

    m_fromDateChooser.setBounds(102, 18, 161, 36);
    m_fromDateChooser.getComponent(1).setEnabled(false);
    fromAndto_DChooser_Panel.add(m_fromDateChooser);
    java.util.Date m_DtFromDate  = (Date) 
    m_fromDateChooser.getModel().getValue();

    fromCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromCalendar.setTime(m_DtFromDate);
    m_DtFromDate = null;
    fromDatePickerClicked();
 }
```

Thanks
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

In JDatePickerImpl update this method

```
/**
 * Called internally to popup the dates.
 */
private void showPopup() {
    if (popup == null){
        PopupFactory fac = new PopupFactory();
        Point xy = getLocationOnScreen();
        datePanel.setVisible(true); 

        int width = button.getWidth();
        int height = formattedTextField.getHeight();

        popup = fac.getPopup(this, datePanel, (int) (xy.getX() - width), (int) (xy.getY() - height + this.getHeight()));
        popup.show();
    }
}
```

Added width and height to show it to the left of the button hiding the formattedTextField.

[image]